# How can I prevent a child from being clicked when the parent is being dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent div, which contains multiple child divs. I want the parent container to be draggable, which in turn should allow all children to be dragged "together". Furthermore, when **not** dragging, I want to be able to click on the children.

I've made a simple example, where the parent is draggable and the children clickable. However, I'm running into the issue that when dragging and releasing, the child element is also clicked. I would like to prevent that, and I don't know how. Since events propagate up the tree and not down, I couldn't figure out how to tell the child to ignore a supposed "click" when the parent is being dragged.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".parent").draggable();

    $(".child").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('blue');
    });
    
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 64px 64px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 64px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `pointer-events: none` on drag start, and remove it on drag end.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".parent").draggable({
        start: function() {
            $(".child").addClass("pointer-ev-none");
        },
        stop: function() {
            $(".child").removeClass("pointer-ev-none");
        }
    });
    
    $(".child").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('blue');
    });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 64px 64px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 64px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

.pointer-ev-none {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```